# Pushing Object to Array inside of another Array in Mongoose/JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multidimensional-array

I am trying to push an object to an array that is inside of another Array in Mongoose. Basically like comments for comments. Here is the structure of my schema here:

```
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  description: {type: String, required: true},
  topics: [{name: String, description: String, responses: [{name: String, description: String}]
});
```

And this is what I have tried so far:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({$and: [{_id: req.body.classId}, {topics: {$elemMatch: {_id: req.body.id}}}]}, 
{$push: {responses: {name: req.body.name, description: req.body.description}}}, 
function(err, result){
  res.send(result);
});
```

This doesn't create any errors and `result` isn't empty is I `console.log` it. I also tried to do it without `$and`, like this: `{_id: req.body.classId, 'topics._id': req.body.id'}` which didn't work either.
Can you also go one level deeper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use positional [$](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator to:

> identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.

E.g.

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { config } from '../../src/config';
import util from 'util';

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  topics: [{ name: String, responses: [{ name: String }] }]
});

const Model = mongoose.model('model', schema);

(async function main() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false });
    const docs = await Model.create([
      { name: 'name a', topics: [{ name: 'topic a', responses: [{ name: 'response a' }] }, { name: 'topic b', responses: [] }] },
      { name: 'name b', topics: [{ name: 'topic b', responses: [{ name: 'response x' }] }] }
    ]);

    const targetDocId = docs[0]._id;
    const targetTopicId = docs[0].topics[0]._id;

    const updatedDoc = await Model.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: targetDocId,
        'topics._id': targetTopicId
      },
      {
        $push: { 'topics.$.responses': { name: 'response b' } }
      },
      { new: true }
    )

    console.log('updatedDoc: ', util.inspect(updatedDoc, false, null))

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    // await mongoose.connection.dropCollection('models');
    await mongoose.connection.close()
  }
})();
```

We pushed a new `{ name: 'response b' }` object to the `responses` array of `topic a`.

Execution logs:

```bash
updatedDoc:  {
  _id: 6464d547fa5ad0bf39f2e93f,
  name: 'name a',
  topics: [
    {
      _id: 6464d547fa5ad0bf39f2e940,
      name: 'topic a',
      responses: [
        { _id: 6464d547fa5ad0bf39f2e941, name: 'response a' },
        { _id: 6464d547fa5ad0bf39f2e948, name: 'response b' }
      ]
    },
    { _id: 6464d547fa5ad0bf39f2e942, name: 'topic b', responses: [] }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```